# Problems with mocking IUnityContainer when testing UnityControllerFactory in MVC project

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, mocking, unity-container, rhino-mocks

I am having trouble testing a unity controller factory. I am mcoking out the unity container and asserting that a method was called on it. I am getting invalid cast expection though but cannot really see what is wrong with my code.

Here is the class under test:

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }

            _container = container;
        }

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            return _container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName);
        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            _container.Teardown(controller);
        }        
    }
```

and here is the test:

```
[Test]
        public void CreateControllerCallsResolveOnContainerWithCorrectArgument()
        {
            const string controllerName = "WhateverController";

            var containerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUnityContainer>();

            var controllerFactory = new UnityControllerFactory(containerMock);

            controllerFactory.CreateController(null, controllerName);

            containerMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Resolve<IController>(controllerName));
        }
```

and here is the error message:

System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'ObjectProxy42336d85f7bb400f9590892348d1d597' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.IController'

Comment: On which line do you get this exception? When I tested your code it worked fine for me.

Comment: On the last line (AssertWasCalled). Hmm. Maybe the version of Rhino Mocks? I am using 3.6 (and Unity 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic `Resolve<T>(string)` method is an extension method and cannot be mocked. You have two choices here:

1. Use a non-generic `Resolve(Type, string)` method or
2. Wrap `IUnityContainer` with your own interface so that the generic methods you want to use are interface methods, not extension methods.

Comment: Aha. That explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, it's an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use  a `IUnityContainer`'s real implementation and register mock/stubs inside it?

Comment: An IoC container has no place in a unit test project. We should be testing the class under test in isolation. I believe that having any config in a unit test project is bad practice.